# Tonality of a song given some chords

Tags: theory, chords, chord-progressions

I have this notes I extracted from a song using Adobe Audition’s frequency analysis.

D F# A C# ([Dmaj7](http://www.8notes.com/piano_chord_chart/dmaj7.asp))

E G B D ([Em7](http://www.8notes.com/piano_chord_chart/em7.asp))

F# A C# E ([F#m7](http://www.8notes.com/piano_chord_chart/fxm7.asp))

G B D F# ([Gmaj7](http://www.8notes.com/piano_chord_chart/gmaj7.asp))

A C# E G ([A7](http://www.8notes.com/piano_chord_chart/a7.asp))

B D F# A ([Bm7](http://www.8notes.com/piano_chord_chart/bm7.asp))

C# E G B ([C#m7b5](http://www.8notes.com/piano_chord_chart/cxm7b5.asp))

In parenthesis is the corresponding chord found by a chord finder. I presume Dmaj7 could be the tonality but I'm not sure, does anyone know what could it be?

Comment: This seems to be a honest enough question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are the 7 chords formed using the notes from the D major scale (D, E, F#, G, A, B, C#). So, yes, the answer is that the progression is in D major